# Can I use ML Kit's face detection for devices without autofocus?

Tags: android, face-detection, google-mlkit

It seems that in live face detection on devices without autofocus ML Kit does not even let the camera start and throws an exception. Is there a way to use it on phones without autofocus? (Live face detection is compulsory)

Comment: You haven't told us anything about how you currently manage the camera. But if you write all the camera handling yourself, then I don't see why you wouldn't be able to use the camera regardless of whether autofocus is available.

Comment: Could you post the exception you got? ML Kit doesn't control whether camera start or not.

Comment: @ChenxiSong I don't have that specific device right now.